# XPath get text between two "p" tags

Tags: parsing, xpath, html-parsing

I can't get the text between `<p> text </p>`

now I have:

```
//span[@class='_39I1Z _2ITlL _3D3LC _3NGVr embTL _1zNVc']/span/p
```

It looks into the span and lists the "p" tags, but what to do next?

structure:

```
<div class="" xpath="1">
<span class="_39I1Z _2ITlL _3D3LC _3NGVr embTL _1zNVc">
    <span>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p><b>Text:</b></p>
        <p></p>
            <ul>
                <li>Text</li>
                <li>Text</li>
                <li>Text</li>
            </ul>
    </span>
</span>
```

tried various combinations. but seems confused

Comment: Are you only interested in the text for that one `p` element, or for all of them under that span? What about the text inside of the `b`?  Update the question showing what you want to select.

Comment: I need all the text in an element <span>

Comment: Frankly, I would just use `string(//span[@class='_39I1Z _2ITlL _3D3LC _3NGVr embTL _1zNVc'])`.

Answer (score 0):

I conquered this problem.

1. The spider was looking at the wrong page
2. `description = cleanhtml(response.xpath("//span[@class='_39I1Z _1KwXc _3kzFG _2zux5 lU8Yn _1o3OU']/span").getall())`
3. because description comes dirty (with html) I cleaned it:

```
import re

def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    return re.sub(re.compile('<.*?>'), '', str(raw_html))
```